# How to run a application with arguments in command prompt using pywinauto or pyautogui?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, pyautogui, pywinauto

I have an application `myapp.exe` and i have the input files `abc1.jpg` and `abc2.jpg` in a folder. I need enter in command prompt `myapp.exe abc1.jpg abc2.jpg` to run the application with arguments. How do I do this using pywinauto or pyautogui

```
from pywinauto import Application
app = Application().start(r"C:\MyFolder\myapp.exe")
```

Here the commandprompt opens.
But I want to enter the arguments as well along with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
from pywinauto import Application
app = Application().start(r"C:\MyFolder\myapp.exe abc1.jpg abc2.jpg")
```